# My thread wont sleep for the specified time

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, sleep

My program is suppose to have race cars "run" a race and then print out who came first.

The main:

```
    /**
     * Load the racers and print them out.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private void run(String the_File) throws IOException {
        try {
            List<Racer> racers = RacerReader.read(the_File);
            Race(racers);
            RacerReport.write(racers);

        } catch (ApplicationException e) {
            LOG.error("An exception was thrown from RacerReader.");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            printEndTimeAndDuration();
            LOG.info("End of Lab8.run().");
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param racers an array list of racers
     * 
     * This method will have the racers run a race and sort them into a list as they finish.
     * The list will be returned at the end.
     * 
     * @return a List of racers.
     */
    public List<Racer> Race(List<Racer> racers){

        List<Racer> finished_racers = new ArrayList<Racer>();

        for(Racer racer : racers) {
            racer.start();
            finished_racers.add(racer);
        }

        return finished_racers;

    }
```

Racer class's run():

```
    /**
     * The thread method.
     */
    public void run() {

        Instant start_running = Instant.now();  

                //random_number_generator is a field in Racer declared as:
                //Random random_number_generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Long randomNum = (long) (random_number_generator.nextInt((10 - 1) + 1) + 1);
        long delay = 90L + randomNum;

        try {
            sleep(delay * 10000);

            Instant finished_time = Instant.now();
            long duration = Duration.between(start_raceing, finished_time).toMillis();

            getFinished(this,duration);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param racer the racer.
     * @param result his time running the race.
     * @return the racer with a new randomized time.
     */
    private Racer getFinished(Racer racer, long result) {

        //update the default result with the new randomized result.
        racer.result = result; 

        //Return the racer with his new time
        return racer; 
    }
```

You may notice sleep(delay * 10000); delay might be 97 milliseconds and you're right I wouldn't be able to see that so I added the 10000 multiplier in to try and slow it down.

Also when I debug in eclipse it will stop at the line for sleep() on a break point; but when I hit continue button to debug more it doesnt seem to activate the getFinished() method which is a problem because it stands I keep getting the exact same result. That result being the data I supplied to the racers in main from a text_file.

Any ideas? I tried scaling the 10,000 up to 1,000,000,000 but it still went by in like a few hundred milliseconds. I also tried using wait() instead but it didnt seem to slow it down either.

Comment: Your fist code snippet is titled, "The main," but there is no `main(...)` shown. You only show a method named `run()` and a sub-routine that it calls.  What calls `run()`? When is it called? Also, you showed part of a class called `Racer`, but where is the rest? Does `Racer` extend `Thread` by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

90*10000 is 900 seconds - 15 minutes. You'd know.

Are you sure you aren't just observing all the racers frozen, doing nothing? 15 minutes is a long time. Try multiplying by 30. Now each racer takes about 2.7 to 3 seconds to finish.

Comment: I suppose that's a fair point however back in main the program will close regardless of 15 mins or not after something like 670 milliseconds. Shouldn't main also stop and wait for the 15 mins why does it keep shooting ahead?

Comment: Oh I can use a seperate for loop and racer.join() to sync everything up never mind thanks @rzwitserloot :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to *assume* that `Racer extends Thread`, and I'm going to assume that you want to know why the `run()` method in your first code snippet returns immediately, no matter how long your `Racers` sleep.

This answer will only be valid if my two assumptions are correct. You can edit your question and show more of your code if I am assuming wrong.

---

Inside that "main" `run()` method, you have a loop:

```
    for(Racer racer : racers) {
        racer.start();
        finished_racers.add(racer);
    }
```

That loop starts each `Racer` (which I *presume* to be a thread), and then it adds the `Racer` to the list of `finished_racers` as soon as the racer is started.*

What does "finished" mean?  Why is a racer "finished" at the exact moment when it is started?

I don't know what's really going on here because you haven't shown all of your code, and you haven't given a complete description of what you expect the code to do or, what it does differently from your expectation. But I hope this "answer" helps.

---

* Actually, it could add a `Racer` to the `finished_racers` list even *before* the `Racer` is started.  When you call `t.start()` for some thread `t`, there's no guarantee that the thread actually will have started to execute your code before the `start()` call returns.